# Wording on memento, Your or his?

Tags: word-usage

What's the correct usage?
This award is presnted to Mr.X on **your** outstanding performance 
 or 
This award is presnted to Mr.X on **his** outstanding performance

Thanks in advance!
Ranjith

Comment: Even if Mr X is present (which looks likely here) and the words are spoken, 'his' is idiomatic and not aloof-sounding. But you're allowed to look at him and smile. As an inscription, certainly 'his'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course,

> This award is presented to Mr.X on **his** outstanding performance.

It is addressed at the world at large. It's not for the awardee to keep reading again and again with pride, but the world to know about the awardee.

Answer (score 0):

Mementos are pretty small, so you can't really write much on them, maybe one or two words. You might have to use a whole roll of Mementos. It would be cool if you wrote a nice poem on them and then dropped them into his Diet Coke. That would be awesome!

Comment: Is "mentos" really short for "mementos"? I always thought the etymology was something to do with menthos?

Comment: Use "comments" to throw in your interesting observations.